# Cannot create Kotlin config for Spring Integration 5.0.4 (Spring 5.0.5)

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-integration

kotlin 1.2.40
spring integration 5.0.4

(was working with 1.2.30 + 4.* spring integration)

try to create integration flow config (several ways):

```
 ...
 .route { m : MyClass -> m.key } 
 ...
 .route ( MyClass::class.java, { m : MyClass -> m.key })
 ...
 //even
 .route<MyClass,String>( object:java.lang.functions.Function<MyClass,String> ...)
```

All those notations compiled but fail at run time while Spring Integration
cannot find method to use as Route.

If config is rewritten in Java - all working.

One thing is that Kotlins lambdas are not of synthetic class while Java's are,
so Spring Integration not sees them as lambdas.

At another hand it worked before and some DSL things as `transform` and some other still work with Kotlin lambdas.

It can be avoided with explicit method name :

```
   .route ({ m : MyClass -> m.key },"apply")
```

While it's very ugly.

Does anyone knew solution except "apply" or shifting @Configuration with Sp Int to Java?

WORKING EXAMPLE ON GITHUB https://github.com/comdiv/kotlin-spring-issue/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/comdiv/TryCreateIntegrationFlowTest.kt

Comment: Maybe you can share some simple project on GH to let us to play with this?

Comment: Why do you spam as everywhere? And you still don't provide a simple project to play... Everybody asks you for that though...

Comment: https://github.com/comdiv/kotlin-spring-issue/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/comdiv/TryCreateIntegrationFlowTest.kt

Comment: Why just not a project we can fork and run? We may miss something during copy/paste. Or you may missed to add something else...

Comment: Those answer (SI)
would close it as Invalid, because Spring Integration doesn't advertise Kotlin support.
But we are open for any suggestions and fixes.

We may help you, but you need to provide a minimal Spring Boot project to let us to play.

Thanks for understanding.

P.S. Since we don't provide an explicit Kotlin support, I don't consider this as critical, more over as bug.

Comment: You can fork and run - just fork it ))) https://github.com/comdiv/kotlin-spring-issue

Comment: That was my comment, because I am in charge in that issue tracker and that is already my authority to decide what and how to do that those tickets :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it works with the `transform()`  because `GenericTransformer` has only one method to select. It worked previously because the `Function` interface was copied from Java 8 to Java 7 code base and only with only one `apply()` method.

So far I see you have a workaround. As a fix I can suggest to modify all the `Function`-based Java DSL EI-methods to specify `apply` method explicitly and don't fall to an ambiguity.

Although I think that is really Kotlin issue that it doesn't honor Java...